# where to put system("pause") in this function?

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

I am trying to pause my screen to test code but i don't know were to put system("pause") anywhere I put it says undefined

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
void load(int*a, int*b, int*c)
{
    printf("Enter 3 numbers");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &(*a), &(*b), &*(c));
}
void calc(int a, int b, int c, int *sum, float *avg)
{
    *sum = a + b + c;
    *avg = *sum / (float)3;
}
void print(int a, int b, int c, int sum, float avg)
{
    printf("The 3 numbers are%d %d %d \n",a, b, c);
    printf("The sum is %d\n", sum);
    printf("The Avg is %f\n", avg);
}

void main()
{
    int a, b, c, sum;
    float avg;
    load(&a, &b, &c);
    calc(a, b, c, &sum, &avg); 
    print(a, b, c, sum,avg);
}
```

Comment: You could just do `getchar()`

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the end of main().

And donnot forget to include its header:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response :) it worked cant believe i forgot that